# How to pass bash variable to a string?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am doing everything in a bash file. I am grabbing to variables from a parameter:

```
brand="$1"
email="$2"
```

Afterwards, I want to include on of them inside of a string:

```
 cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/

 echo 'server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  $brand.mydomain.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/$brand/soon;
 }' >> default
```

But it echo's $brand.mydomain.com. How to echo the actual value which I am passing as parameter?

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quote in `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't allow for expansion of **anything**. Double quotes allow for expansion of variable, but you best enclose the name with parenthesis as shown.

```
echo "server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ${brand}.mydomain.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/${brand}/soon;
}" >> default
```

Comment: No need for the braces here.  The `.` and the `/` characters are not valid variable name characters so they terminate the name.  The practice of enclosing with braces is often needed in csh where the expansions are different, but only in bash when surrounded by alphanumerics or underscores.